# Bing maps WPF multitouchdemo

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps, multi-touch

I have created a simple WPF application that has a Bing Map. The problem is when I try to run my program on PC with touch input it becomes really unstable: when you try to scale or translate the map it lags hard.
By the way, the same application runs normally on a desktop where you can use only your mouse to navigate. And also, when you open Bing Maps in browser on this touch device everything is okay so the problem is in the code and not related with hardware, I think.

I did some positive steps: now I am handling manipulation events in my code (at the first time I did not implement any control functions for the map, so every manipulation was handled by default event handlers). It has improved the situation and the map is not so laggy when you try to scale or translate it.

But I got another problem. During the application workflow I add about 200 polylines to the map and when it happens the problem with touch control returns and map becomes unstable again.

Here is some code from the project:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="NYCTraffic.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"

        ManipulationDelta="Window_ManipulationDelta" 

        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <m:Map Name="map" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"
                   CredentialsProvider="myKey"
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="map_MouseLeftButtonDown" SupportedManipulations="Translate,Scale"
                   IsManipulationEnabled="True" TouchUp="map_TouchUp" AnimationLevel="None"
                   Center="40.714623, -74.006605" ZoomLevel="13" >
        </m:Map>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    map.Focus();
    map.ZoomLevel = DEFAULT_ZOOM;
}

private void Window_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Manipulators.Count() == 1)
    {
        long dx = (long)-e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        long dy = (long)-e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
        if (Math.Abs(dx) >= SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
            Math.Abs(dy) >= SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
        {
            var p = map.Center;
            var pLocal = map.LocationToViewportPoint(p);
            pLocal.Offset(dx, dy);
            map.Center = map.ViewportPointToLocation(pLocal);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        map.ZoomLevel = Math.Log(Math.Pow(2, map.ZoomLevel) * e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Length / Math.Sqrt(2), 2);
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

That is not the whole text of the program, but I think it is the most relevant for my problem.

So, does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: This is a known issue. The WPF control was built before Windows 8 and was designed to work with the touch sensors in the original Microsoft Surface devices (table top computer).

Comment: @rbrundritt Okay, quite sad =( So, Does it mean that there is no possible way to avoid this problem in WPF application?

Comment: I haven't come across anyone who has managed to sort this out on their own. Usually they just disable the touch events. This is logged as a bug to be fixed in the WPF control.

Comment: @rbrundritt. Unfortunately, I cannot afford myself disabling the touch events. In my application I tried to use another maps (http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) and it helped a little - now touch manipulation looks almost good, but there are several minor disadvantages so it's not a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps WPF map control has been updated with a fix for the touch functionality. You can download the updated library here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27165

Alternatively you can also access the map control libraries using Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF/1.0.0.3